# Unable to launch My first App on AVD

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse, Created AVD and able to launch it perfectly.
 I tried to launch my first app using 
 Run as -> 1 Android Application. 
 but there is no response either from Eclipse or AVD

Comment: make sure that you are clicking on the project package when you run

Comment: make sure to give proper target version

Comment: When the ADV is launched and the emulator has been loaded. There is a view on Eclipse called "Devices", go there and check if appears your emulator as "emulator:5554", if not go to a down arrow in the same view at the upper right corner and select reset adb. Once connected try to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I Accidentally used activity_main.xml instead of MainActivity.java and tried to run it. so, i didn't have any response. now problem solved.